# Select between "last october" and today

Tags: mysql, date, select

still a beginner when it comes to SQL queries.
I need to select fields from a table with a date field from e.g. last 1st October until today.

Something like

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE table.date BETWEEN ***last october*** and CURDATE()
```

So, what can I put in instead of *last october* that it will work without touching it in a year again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check if the current month is october -> december. In that case, I can get october of the current year, else, I'd get october of last year :

```
-- returns <current year>-10-01 if we are in octobre, november or december, else <current year - 1>-10-01
SELECT CONCAT(IF(MONTH(CURDATE()) >= 10, YEAR(CURDATE()), YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1),'-10-01');
```

---

```
SELECT field
FROM table
WHERE table.date BETWEEN
      CONCAT(IF(MONTH(CURDATE()) >= 10, YEAR(CURDATE()), YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1),'-10-01')
  and
      CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a couple of sub-queries:

a) Current month:

```
mysql> select month(now());
+--------------+
| month(now()) |
+--------------+
|           11 |
+--------------+
```

b) Get comparison year, e.g. if Oct 1 this year passed then return current year otherwise the previous year:

```
mysql> select case when month(now()) >= 10 then year(now()) else year(now()) - 1 end;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| case when month(now()) >= 10 then year(now()) else year(now()) - 1 end |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                   2020 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

c) construct date for the last 1st October:

```
mysql> select concat(case when month(now()) >= 10 then year(now()) else year(now()) - 1 end, '-10-01');
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat(case when month(now()) >= 10 then year(now()) else year(now()) - 1 end, '-10-01') |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2020-10-01                                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The last query is replacement for ***last october***

Therefore the final query is:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE table.date BETWEEN CONCAT(CASE WHEN MONTH(NOW()) >= 10 THEN YEAR(NOW()) ELSE YEAR(NOW()) - 1 END, '-10-01') AND DATE(NOW())
```